# How to make ionic 3 autoscroll for chat app work?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have tried every solution but nothing has worked. I am building a chat app where i want it to be scrolled to last message automatically,also when new message comes it scrolls to the bottom.

I have tried scrollTo() on the #content but it doesn't work

**chat.html**

```
<ion-content #content *ngIf="buddy">
  <div class = "chatwindow">
    <ion-list no-lines *ngIf="allmessages">
      <ion-item *ngFor = "let item of allmessages; let i = index" text-wrap>
        <ion-avatar item-left *ngIf="item.sentby === buddy.uid">
          <img src="{{buddy?.photoURL}}">
        </ion-avatar>
        <div class="bubble me" *ngIf="item.sentby === buddy.uid">
          <h3 *ngIf="!imgornot[i]">{{item.message}}</h3>
          <img src="{{item?.message}}" *ngIf="imgornot[i]">
        </div>
        <ion-avatar item-right *ngIf="item.sentby != buddy.uid">
          <img src="{{photoURL}}">
        </ion-avatar>
        <div class="bubble you" *ngIf="item.sentby != buddy.uid">
          <h3 *ngIf="!imgornot[i]">{{item.message}}</h3>
          <img src="{{item?.message}}" *ngIf="imgornot[i]">
        </div>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </div>
  </ion-content>
```

**chat.ts**

```
      @ViewChild('content') content: Content;
  scrolltoBottom() {
    setTimeout(() => {
   //   this.content.scrollToBottom();
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Comment: Looks correct, but not sure what is issue. Just one thing content scroll is in comment line but still create working demo at https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this.

```
export class ChatPage {

@ViewChild('content') content: Content;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.scrolltoBottom()
}

scrolltoBottom() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.content.scrollToBottom();
    }, 300);
} }
```

Comment: my code is like this, I just shared a snippet! and this does not work.